# How to flip the boolean value in a nested function

Tags: python, list, boolean, nested-function

I have a problem regarding flipping the boolean value. I'd like to do the flip inside another function. The code is similar to this one:

```
def printChange():
    isChange = [True]
    change(isChange)
    print(isChange)

def change(x):
    x = [False]

printChange() # [True]
```

If I modify the change function like this:

```
def printChange():
    isChange = [True]
    change(isChange)
    print(isChange)

def change(x):
    x[0] = False

printChange() #[False]
```

I am curious about why this happens. I guess it should be related to some mutability stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Assigning to a name does not change the object previously referred to by the name. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. (`x[0] = ...` is *not* an assignment to a name; it's special syntax for `x.__setitem__(0, ...)`.)

Comment: @chepner Thank you! I have read through this article and it really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the local value `x` in not `isChange` this function:

```
def change(x):
    x = [False]
```

You need to return the desired value:

```
def change(x):
    return [False]
```

Or better yet if you want to flip the value:

```
def change(x):
    return [not x[0]]
```

Then in `printChange` you need to assign the return value to `isChange`:

```
def printChange():
    isChange = [True]
    isChange = change(isChange)
    print(isChange)
```

Comment: Hi Jab, thanks for your reply. If you see my second code block, when I do 
def change(x):
    x[0] = false 
and it successfully changes the ischange to [False] with using a return. I am more interested to see why this is the case here.

Comment: Because you are modifying the data referenced not the reference.

Comment: Got cha! Thank you!